# Проверка логина,админ или обычный пользователь. Laravel

Tags: laravel

[image: это таблица 'users']У меня Регистрация Laravel Auth, при регистрации в базе данных в таблице 'users',у user - type = 0 (default), а у admin, type = 1 , надо при логине проверить,если type == 1,вход в профиль admin, если type == 0, вход в профиль user, и обычный user не может зайти в страницу admin. Как в контроллере логина Laravel Auth это проверить?

> Route

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {
  Route::get('/admin/users', "Admin@adminPanel");
});
```

> Controller

```
use Auth;
class Admin extends Controller
{    
  function adminPanel(){
     return view('/admin');
}
```

> Kernel

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,
```

> Middleware

```
    namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
class Admin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
     public function handle($request, Closure $next)
     {
            if (Auth::user() &&  Auth::user()->type == 1) {
                return $next($request);
            }
            return abort(404);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Делаете middleware. Его используете в группе роутов. Или в контроллере, если точечно.

Comment: а как указать кто такой  type из базы данных?

Comment: вам пример сбросили. Все роуты админские помещайте в группу роутов. Должно работать. Если нет, то кидайте свой код.

Comment: На крйняк выложите на github проект.

Comment: @TyomArshakyan Получается сейчас: пользователь не может зайти в админку, а админ может + админ может зайти на простую страницу, а вам нужно, чтобы админ не могу зайти на простую страницу? В группе роутов не нужно прописывать адрес `/admin` для контроллеров, т.к используется префикс роутов `admin`

Comment: '/admin/users' это типа главная страница админа,он должен при логине зайти туда,,,а здесь - prefix' => 'admin' ,этот  'admin' это вроде страница админа?

Comment: @TyomArshakyan дополнил ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я делал таким образом:

Создаем middleware `Admin`

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Admin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user() &&  Auth::user()->type == 1) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return abort(404);
    }
}
```

В `Kernel.php` в `$routeMiddleware` добавляешь

```
'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,
```

В роуте используй

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {

  Route::get('/', 'контроллер');

});
```

Для переадресации после авторизации в контроллер `LoginController` нужно добавить:

```
protected function authenticated()
{
    if(Auth::user()->type == 1) {
        return redirect('/admin');
    } else {
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Comment: не работает,админ тоже попадает в страницу обычного пользователя,хотя его type == 1.

Comment: да, так все работает,спасибо большое,очень помогли)))